# Java Jersey and servlet filters

Tags: java, servlets, filter, jersey

I'm planning to build a REST API based on Jersey to replace a previous servlet-based API. However, I have some filters which are applied to the servlet-based API: an encryption/decryption filter and a GZIP filter.
Since these filters are servlet filters, can I keep them and expect them to work with Jersey just like the previous servlet model, or there are any issues related to this?
Can servlet filtering be directly applied to Jersey without any modifications?

Comment: I know it's an old one but can you provide the filter you created ?

Answer (score 0):

JERSEY does not mandate to use any of its filter, which can create a conflict with user defined filters. Jersey requires only to configure the framework servlet and NO filters in web.xml. I have used Jersey with my own filter implementations for things like authentication. It works like a charm, so don't worry.